# Get data from same table with child rows in same collection using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table with multiple rows, which contain parent and child rows, in case I need to get data to the same collection. This means getting child row data inside the parent row using laravel.

| id | type | price | is_substitute | subsitute_parent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Type A | 12 | 0 | null |
| 2 | Type B | 44 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Type C | 23 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | Type D | 11 | 0 | null |
| 5 | Type E | 45 | 1 | 4 |
| 6 | Type F | 25 | 1 | 4 |

"subsitute_parent" id means the parent row id of this table. How can I do this using laravel.

I tried using get all data from the table and the add collection to foreach and then create parent row array and child row array, but this method is not efficient.

```
$returnedData = ItemModel::all();
$structPODetails = [];

foreach ($returnedData as  $tableRow) {
    if (!empty($tableRow->subsitute_parent)) {
       $structPODetails['child_items'][] = $tableRow;
    } else {
       $structPODetails['parent_items'][] = $tableRow;
    }
}

return $structPODetails;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood

**In `ItemModel.php`**

```
class ItemModel extends Model
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ItemModel::class, 'subsitute_parent');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ItemModel::class, 'subsitute_parent');
    }
}
```

Then in the controller, add.

```
$structPODetails = ItemModel::with('children')->get();
```

This will give you output as

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        ...
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                ..
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        ...
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                ...
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                ..
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

use laravel Eloquent way.

In the model add relationship has many

```
public function substitutes()
{

  return $this->hasMany(ItemModel::class, 'subsitute_parent');
}
```

and in your controller

```
$substitutes = ItemModel::with([
        'substitutes' =>
        function ($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('subsitute_parent');
        }
    ])->whereHas(
            'substitutes',
            function ($query) {
                $query->whereNotNull('subsitute_parent');
            }
        )->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Model Logic

```
 public function substitutes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'subsitute_parent');
    }
```

controller logic

```
  $substitutes = ItemModel::with(['substitutes'])->whereHas('substitutes', function ($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('subsitute_parent');
        })->get();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).